# Perché "ubbidire" ha smesso di essere più usato di "obbedire"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, single-words

Il verbo *obbedire* è quasi identico al latino *oboedire*. È ragionevole pensare che questa trasformazione si sia avuta prima del passaggio ad *ubidire* e *ubbidire* poi. In ogni caso quest'ultimo ha storicamente preso il sopravvento, tant'è che il De Mauro e il Garzanti riportano *obbedire* come variante (così come le versioni con una sola "b", ma sono davvero poco usate).

In particolare, nella seconda metà del 18° secolo aveva raggiunto una superiorità [schiacciante](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ubbidire%2Cobbedire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cubbidire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobbedire%3B%2Cc0) secondo Google Ngram. Ma nonostante i dizionari sopracitati affermino che oggi hanno pressoché la stessa frequenza, il grafico che ho linkato mostra un rapporto di 3 a 1 a favore di *obbedire*; anche solo cercandoli separatamente su Google, si trovano quasi il doppio dei risultati per *obbedire*.

Cos'ha causato questa grande inversione di tendenza? Sembra essere un fenomeno iniziato con l'Illuminismo, e poi continuato.

Comment: Quest'osservazione mi sorprende: se mi aveste chiesto a freddo io avrei senza dubbio alcuno detto che *ubbidire* è il più comune dei due...

Comment: Se ubbidire ad un certo punto viene percepito come termine più popolare rispetto ad obbedire (più vicino all'etimo latino) questo può spiegare l'inversione di tendenza. http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ubbidire-o-obbedire_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Comment: La mia impressione è che *obbedire* sia posteriore a *ubbidire*, in quanto di formazione “colta”; che nella lingua scritta sia prevalente il primo non mi sorprende, per l'influsso di sciocche imposizioni scolastiche. Personalmente non avrei dubbi per il secondo.

Comment: @egreg: Sì in effetti potrebbe essere che l'evoluzione naturale sia stata solo in *ubbidire*, mentre quella in *obbedire* sia stata artificiale. Sarebbe interessante qualche riscontro. Comunque a me piace più quest'ultimo, ma anch'io ritengo sciocche le imposizioni dall'alto. Se si è trattato di questo, me le sarei però aspettate in epoca rinascimentale, con un calo di *ubbidire* già da allora, invece Ngram lo dà in forte crescita fino al 1750...

Comment: Per me è più naturale “obbedire”. Non mi è ben chiaro il discorso delle imposizioni: qualche autorità ha imposto “obbedire” sopra “ubbidire”?

Comment: Perché il voto negativo?

Comment: Se chi dà voti negativi commentasse per spiegare il perché, farebbe qualcosa di potenzialmente utile. Altrimenti rasenta il vandalismo.

Comment: Il "vandalo" sono io,  mi sembrava chiaro. Non capisco perché rifiuti la spiegazione data da Treccani. Forse vuoi fare il difficile.

Comment: @Gio: Dai, "non fare l'antipatico". :) Sinceramente non avevo capito bene il tuo commento, perché non sembravi alludere alle possibili imposizioni scolastiche chiamate in causa da egreg. Se vi alludevi, resta il fatto che me le sarei aspettate durante il Rinascimento, e secondo Ngram non è stato così. Altrimenti continuo a non capirlo, dato che di certo il popolo non si sarebbe fatto problemi a continuare a privilegiare il termine più *popolare*.

Comment: Non vorrei dire una cavolata, ma a me sembra che abbiano due sfumature diverse: si _ubbidisce_ alla mamma ma si _obbedisce_ a un ordine. Non ce lo vedo Garibaldi a dire _ubbidisco!_

Comment: @CarLa: Sospetto che proprio esempi "canonici" come quello di Garibaldi abbiano plasmato la tua percezione :) La Crusca [riporta](http://vocabolario.sns.it/cgi-bin/Vocabolario/search_context?rimando=1&pattern=OBBEDIRE.&tag_n=ENTRY&attr_n=ID&attr_v=W6) questo estratto di _Scelte Novelle antiche e moderne_: "Il quale obbediendo al Re, pervertì tutto 'l fatto".

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ubbidire-o-obbedire_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Comment: @alexjo: Come detto nel corpo della domanda, Ngram e il confronto dei risultati di ricerche su Google indicano che la diffusione non è la stessa.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva si ho visto, ma personalmente sono estremamente dubbioso su statistiche fatte con Ngram così indietro nel tempo... per quanto mi concerne ho avuto una preferenza per obbedire, forse perché era quello più usato a scuola e di sapore più letterario e forse perché preponderante nel linguaggio della Chiesa, almeno ai miei tempi...

Comment: Notiamo anche che un andamento [simile](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obbedienza%2Cubbidienza&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobbedienza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cubbidienza%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cobbedienza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cubbidienza%3B%2Cc0) c'è per "obbedienza" ed "ubbidienza". Potrebbe forse avere a che fare con un'influenza francese post Napoleonica tramite "obéir"?

Comment: Personalmente trovo che abbiano assunto caratteri diversi e non siano più completamente sinonimi: il bambino ubbidisce (non credo di aver mai sentito una mamma dire "obbedisci!"), il militare obbedisce agli ordini. Se questa considerazione fosse corretta , analisi di frequenza d'uso non avrebbero validità perchè cambierebbero i contesti di applicazione.